# How to use f:loadBundle in ui:composition template child

Tags: templates, jsf-2, facelets

I have a "test.xhtml", based on a template:

```
    <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        template="/templates/BasicTemplate.xhtml">
        <f:loadBundle basename="label" var="label" />
...
    <h:commandButton value="#{label.buttonname}" ...></h:commandButton>
...
```

The file "label.properties" is located in WEB-INF/classes.
But when I load it in my browser, there was no replacement, but instead of the expected  name I got "label.buttonname" upon my button.
This problem only appears if I use it with templating.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I got it: 
This is WRONG (!). LoadBudle is between composition and define tag.

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    template="/templates/BasicTemplate.xhtml">
    <f:loadBundle basename="label" var="label" /> <--- WRONG place!!!
    <ui:define name="content">
        <h:commandButton value="#{label.buttonname}" ...></h:commandButton>
    </ui:define>
```

This is fine:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    template="/templates/BasicTemplate.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">
        <f:loadBundle basename="label" var="label" />
        <h:commandButton value="#{label.buttonname}" ...></h:commandButton>
    </ui:define>
```